# NodeJS require module namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mjs

I thought about having my, on npmjs released, module split into 2 or more parts (versioned), but both easily requirable / importable.

The result should be:

```js
//index1.js
const themodule = require('mymodule');

//index2.js
const themodule = require('mymodule/v2');

//index.mjs
import themodule from 'mymodule/v2';
```

Kind of this style.

I tried creating a subfolder named `v2` in the path where the package.json:main property field points to. Did not work.

I can't seem to figure out how to be able to use the '/' in the module name / get it into there.

A helpful hint / push into the right direction would be great.

edit:
folder structure:

```
package.json  main->lib/mod.js
lib/mod.js
lib/v2/mod.js
```

Comment: Hmm as long as there is an index.js file with module.exports in the v2 folder you should be fine.

Comment: Don't use directory structure to version, use semantic versioning when you publish to npm. This is the accepted convention.

Comment: Maybe i should have called it design1 and design2. Or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution seems to be exactly as @Bergur pointed out:

```
package.json:main     -> lib/index.js
lib/index.js          (version 1)
v2/package.json:main  -> ./index.js  (just needs a handful basic fields)
v2/index.js           (version 2)
```

this enables above handling with require. not sure about import.